# Printing the dynamic value of a variable, in HTML, without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, text

I have a variable,

```
var default_user = "Guest"
```

The value of this variable changes when a user submits their name through an input field, like so:

```
$( ".inputfield" ).keypress( function( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) { 
        if( $('.inputfield').val() == "" ) {

        } else {

            default_user = $('.inputfield').val();

        }
    }
});
```

How do I print the updated value of this variable in a HTML text-element (after a new value has been submitted), without having to reload my page?

Comment: i don't get your question - add a `console.log(default_user)` at last line in your `else` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a span and just set updated value in that span.

```js
$( ".inputfield" ).keypress( function( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) { 
        if( $('.inputfield').val() == "" ) {

        } else {

            default_user = $('.inputfield').val();
$("#yourSpan").text(default_user);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @W4yp01nt Glad i could help!